# Higher dimensional array vs 1-D array efficiency in C++

Tags: c++, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I'm curious about the efficiency of using a higher dimensional array vs a one dimensional array.  Do you lose anything when defining, and iterating through an array like this:

```
array[i][j][k];
```

or defining and iterating through an array like this:

```
array[k + j*jmax + i*imax];
```

My inclination is that there wouldn't be a difference, but I'm still learning about high efficiency programming (I've never had to care about this kind of thing before).

Thanks!

Comment: It depends upon how you declare and create the array. `int array[5][5][5]` will yield different performance than `int ***array;`

Comment: AFAIK, the elements in the second array are contiguous, while the elements in the first one aren't. So accessing 1-D array should be faster. Another point is that the first array definition will lead to a higher degree of memory fragmentation.

Comment: +1 to @Rob, but pedantically, only the first one is a multi-dimensional array.  The second is (a pointer to) an array of pointers to arrays (of pointers to arrays).

Comment: @Helper: C++ arrays are contiguous regardless of dimensionality.

Comment: @Helper, if the array is declared `int array[5][5][5]`, then the elements are contiguous, and will not cause any more or less memory fragmentation than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is to benchmark both ways (with optimization flags on in the compiler of course).  The one think you lose for sure in the second method is the clarity of reading.

Answer (score 1):

The former way and the latter way to access arrays are identical once you compile it. Keep in mind that accessing memory locations that are close to one another does make a difference in performance, as they're going to be cached differently. Thus, if you're storing a high-dimensional matrix, ensure that you store rows one after the other if you're going to be accessing them that way.

In general, CPU caches optimize for temporal and spacial ordering. That is, if you access memory address X, the odds of you accessing X+1 are higher. It's much more efficient to operate on values within the same cache line.

Check out this article on CPU caches for more information on how different storage policies affect performance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

Answer (score 1):

If you can rewrite the indexing, so can the compiler. I wouldn't worry about that.

Trust your compiler(tm)!

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on implementation, but I'd say it more or less amounts to your code for one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and care about such things after *profiling the code*. It is very unlikely that something like that will affect the performance of the application as a whole. Using the correct algorithms is much more important

And even if it does matter, it is most certainly only a single inner loop that needs attention.